# Ember Data relationships not resolved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm still learning ember.js and have run into a roadblock with ember data not resolving lookup relationships in models.  I have one model 'site' that will be basically a lookup table for every other model to differentiate data based on location.

At this point, I'm doing something wrong or missing a key concept - probably both... (or maybe it's the wee hour!)

**Site Model** (i.e. the lookup table)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
});
```

The site model would have a hasMany relationship to all my other models (will be about 12 when complete)

**Associate Model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    site: belongsTo('site'),
    last: DS.attr(),
    first: DS.attr(),
    active: DS.attr('boolean'),

fullName: Ember.computed('first', 'last', function() {
  return `${this.get('first')} ${this.get('last')}`;
  }),
});
```

The 'associate model' will also be a lookup along with 'site' in some other models.

I'm providing data via the JSON API spec but I'm not including the relationship data because as I understand it, ember data it should be pulling down the site data using the site id attribute.

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "/maint/associates"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "associate",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "site": "6",
                "last": "Yoder",
                "first": "Steven",
                "active": "1"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/associates/1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In my template file I'm referencing associate.site which gives me an error.

> <(unknown mixin):ember431>

If I use associate.code or .name to match the site model, nothing will show in the template.  The code from the 'site' table is the data I really want to displayed in the template.

So the obvious questions:

1. Am I wrong that Ember Data should be resolving this or do I need to
   include the relationship in my API response?
2. I realize that my belongsTo in the 'associate' model only references
   site while I want site.code, so how do I make that relationship
   known or access the field in my 'associate' model?
3. I didn't include hasMany relationship in the 'site' model because
   there would be many.  Do I need to do an inverse relationship in
   other models? Examples I've seen don't all show the hasMany
   relationships setup.
4. When I look at the models in ember inspector the site field is not
   included in the model.  Even if I wasn't getting the correct data
   should it still show up?

I like ember so far, just need to understand and get over this roadblock

Update: My backend JSON library would only generate relationship links based on the current spec which would be

```
"related": "/streams/1/site"
```

but ember data does call

"related": "/sites/1"

to resolve the relationship

So @Adam Cooper answer is correct if you generate links as he answered or if you can only generate the links based on the current specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the JSONAPIAdapter, which is the default, you want your response to look this:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "/maint/associates"
  },
  "data": [{
    "type": "associate",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "last": "Yoder",
      "first": "Steven",
      "active": "1"
    },
    relationships: {                  
      "site": {
        "links": {  
          related: "/sites/6"
        }
      } 
    }
  }]
}
```

That will allow Ember Data to look up the site via its relationship. Right now Ember is trying to access the site model which Ember Data can't populate hence the error you're getting. As an aside you could probably do with returning an actual boolean value for active too.

Comment: I need to look at my backend library to determine how to change the json to match.

Comment: Which backend library are you using? You might just be able to switch to a different adapter.

Comment: sorry hit enter too soon.  php backend using jsonapi by lode to generate, Slim for routing. jsonapi generates:

    "self": "/streams/1/relationships/site"
    
which matches the current json api spec.  Took a bit to add correct routing. I want to mark as answer because Ember is now requesting data but ember inspector shows record with null field values.  Console shows 
record with values in response, just not getting put into Store.

Comment: Probably worth starting another question to get to the bottom of that

Comment: I figured it out.  I was returning an array when Ember was looking for a single object when resolving. Until I realized Ember was using /sites/6 not the links the backend generated, I was chasing the wrong route to fix. thanks again.